# java get the current computer's date

Tags: java

how can i get computer's date on java, i want just year, month, day
i tried to get calender like this

```
Calendar c =Calendar.getInstance();
        c.clear(Calendar.HOUR)
```

but can't know to deal with it,

Comment: This may help [Java Date, Calendar](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaDateTimeAPI/article.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First link on google:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

private String getDateTime() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
```

Comment: @11684 just one thing please, i got the answer like this `2012/07/01` how could i make it like this `2012-07-01` ?

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? It is the accepted answer, so the OP is content with it: see his last comment on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ONE line of code.....

**// Prints 01-07-2012**

```
 System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY").format(new Date()));
```

**// Prints 01-Jul-2012**

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY").format(new Date()));
```

Comment: `YYYY` should be lowercase: `yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the current date as a `year/month/day` string like this:

```
String strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
System.out.println(strDate);
> 2012-07-01
```

Notice that a [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object will *always* contain year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, etc., and by calling `new Date()` you obtain a date object with the current time.

If you only need some fields of a date (say, year, month and day) you need to format the date using a formatter, for instance [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Check the link for learning more about the string formatting options available in Java.

Comment: how can i get it like this `2012-07-01` ?

Comment: Simply change the format string, in the above code use `"yyyy-MM-dd"`

Answer (score 1):

```
    Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    int y = rightNow.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int m = rightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int d = rightNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println("year "+y+"  month "+m+"  day "+d);
```

Comment: your code gives me this `2012-7-1` but i want this `2012-07-01`

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

Some example code using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.4 library.

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use either Joda-Time or the new java.time package in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310).

### Time Zone

Note the use of a time zone. A time zone is necessary to determine a date. The same simultaneous moment in Kolkata and Paris may have different dates on the calendar. If you omit a time zone, the JVM’s current default time zone will be applied. That means your results may vary, so best to explicitly specify the time zone you intend.

### Example Code

```
String output = LocalDate.now( TimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ).toString();
```